# What happens to all the zygotes and fetuses that are aborted or miscarried? Do they get a pass to go to heaven?

Tags: abortion

I have heard Christians claim that the zygotes and fetuses that are aborted or miscarried get a free pass to go to heaven. Is this true? I can't find anywhere in the Bible where this is the case. The Bible itself declares that there is only one name under heaven given among men whereby one may be saved and that is Jesus. Is there a possibility that those who are zygotes or fetuses do not have an afterlife?